# WrapFigure package drifting off to the left side, how do I prevent this behavior?

Tags: math-mode, graphics, floats, align, wrapfigure

I want my images on the right side of the PDF to maintain alignment on the right side and not "drift off" to the left side, as can be seen in here:  [image]

I only run into this issue when there are multiple wrapfigures near each other, in my previous notes where there are only two figures that are slightly farther apart from each other, it looks fine: [image]

I've tried changing the order of the code and where the wrapfigures are, but it only works correctly if I add more "paragraphs" which would be redundant in this case.

Here are the links to the images that I'm using within the wrapfigure enviorement

param2.jpg: [image]
param2_v.jpg: [image]

Here is the code that is giving me the issue as in the first image:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}
\documentclass[10pt, welsh, english, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\input{glyphtounicode}
%Indenting
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%Mathematical tools for fractions
%\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Basic Packages for Encoding (Input AND Output) and Langauge Support
%\usepackage[english]{babel} %Throws errors, just use babel by itself.
%\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babel}
% Change Layout with a User-Friendly Interface
\usepackage{enumitem,url,fancyref}
%\usepackage{enumitem,geometry,url,fancyref}
% Include Pictures with a User-Friendly Interface
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %Keep aspect ratio and resize
% Extended Math Support from the Famous 'American Mathematical Society'
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Physics package, mostly for the \abs command.
\usepackage{physics}
%Additional
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{animate} %To animate gifs, utilize imagemagick to convert the gif to several pngs by this command: (convert foo.gif foo.png), if the results are suboptimal try: (convert foo.gif -coalesce foo.png), you may probably get foo-0.png, foo-1.png... then use this code to animate them:     \animategraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,autoplay,loop,nomouse,controls]{12}{./Animated/animate_}{0}{99}
\usepackage{csquotes}
   \MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
   \MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}
   \usepackage[tt=lining]{cfr-lm}
%Other optimizations
\geometry{scale=.9}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%Necessary for table of contents
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % for 'DarkGreen' color
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\color{red}\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\color{blue}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\color{black}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\color{DarkGreen}}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\color{red}     \cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\color{blue}     \cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\color{black} \cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\color{DarkGreen} \cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\color{red}%\large\bfseries
}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Indigo,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=Indigo,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    citecolor=black
}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}

\textbf{Problem 2:}

\begin{align*}
    x&=4\sin t  &y&=-3\cos t&(x,y)\\
\end{align*}

For efficiency, we will find the values between 0 to \(\frac{\pi}{2}\), then use the symmetries of \(\sin\)  and \(\cos\) for the rest of the points, graphing in increasing orders of t and showing the direction.


\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{./images/param2.jpg}
    \caption*{Plotting of \(x=4 \sin t\), \(y=-3 \cos t\) with restriction \(0 \leq t < 2\pi \)}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{./images/param2_v.jpg}
        \caption*{Plotting of \(x=4 \sin t\), \(y=-3 \cos t\) with restriction \(0 \leq t < \pi \)}
        \end{wrapfigure}

\begin{align*}
    t   &&  x&=4 \sin t  &y&=-3 \cos t&(x,y)\\
    0&     &0&     &-&3    &(0,-3)\\
    \frac{\pi}{6}&     &2&     &-&\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}     &(2,-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2})\\
    \frac{\pi}{4}&      &2&\sqrt{2}     &-&\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}     &(2\sqrt{2},\frac{-3\sqrt{2}}{2})\\
    \frac{\pi}{3}&      &2&\sqrt{3}     &-&\frac{3}{2}     &(2\sqrt{3},-\frac{3}{2})\\
    \frac{\pi}{2}&      &4&     &0&     &(4,0)\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I believe it's compatible now, apologies not including it, the packages were all part of the document but this document is quite large, so most of those packages are not necessarily related to what is in the question, but they are being compiled alongside the problematic issue that i'm posting about.

Comment: we can not run the example to see the issue as we don't have `./images/param2.jpg`  please use `example-image` (which is generally available) or simply `\rule{1cm}{2cm}` (or whatever size you need, also iplease remove any packages not needed to show the issue, as that makes debugging a lot easier. (it is easy for you to check that the issue still occurs if you delete a package before posting)

Comment: but you are specifying wrapfig but then not supplying any paragraph text that could take the cutout (an `align` is always full width) so there is no text  to hold the figure to the right.

Comment: @DavidCarlisleI went ahead and added the images, I've tried adding a one line of text to both sides but to no avail.

It only works correctly if I add paragraphs in between the two images (but that would be redundant as I rather my notes be concise and to the point without redundancy in wording)

Comment: Probably you could make use of minipages?

Comment: Looks like you want to have pictures in the margin, like in Tufte´s books or the Feynman lectures. Maybe you should try `marginfigure` from [sidenotes](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/sidenotes/sidenotes.pdf) instead

Comment: I've tried out the marginnotes and sidenotes packages, unfortunately they don't wrap text around them, thus they wouldn't be convenient for me to use, and for the images to be proper sized they'd need a much larger margin, unlike the wrapfigure package which allows the text to be both on top and below of the figure without affecting the whole page's margin size.